# How to hide Map drive from remote domain users

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

I am wondering how can i hide a map drive from remote domain (server2012r2) users, our mapped K drive is shared with everyone so any one login to domain they will see the K drive mapped on their computers so i want to know if is there any way i can hide K drive from some users, i cannot access deny to those users because our folder redirection is mapped to K drive if i setup access deny to those users they wouldn't be able to see any thing on their desktops, documents and appdata folders.
Thanks.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445). Why don't you want a drive mapped to a location users have permission to access? Is it because there's something there you don't want to see? If so, you're going about this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup 2 groups. Show-Mapped-Drive and Dont-Show-Mapped-Drive. Put the respective users in the two groups. Now in Group Policy when you map the drive create two mappings for K:. With each targeting a group. In the mapping for Dont-Show-Mapped-Drive you can choose to hide the drive.

Please note this of course depends on how you map drives. Also note, that if Show Hidden Drives is turned on it will show them the drive.

Comment: Thanks for responding i gave already created huge map drive gpo and linked to contractors group but it's not hidding the drive so temporarily I am running tasks scheduler on those machines to unmap the drive at user login.

Comment: We had this issue when we first attempted a hide drive mapping. We had to push out an unmapping first. Then we had to use Update instead of Create.

Comment: Okay let try that but I don't want to un map drive from everyone though.

Comment: @user313162 that's why it's important to configure the item-level targeting to only affect the users you don't want to have the drive.

Comment: I have tried with item level targeting by using groups but nothing helped I guess I have to unmap k drive some how first then I might be able to hide it using item level targeting.